# Problem in sending email with exim in cpanel to extern address

Tags: exim

I noticed today that mails do not come through. Since several hours ago, all mails just get stuck in queue. I have tried to deliver them manually, by selecting one mail in WHM Mail Queue Manager and clicking on "Deliver Selected", but after few minutes I just get this error:
Code:

```
LOG: MAIN
cwd=/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot 4 args: /usr/sbin/exim -v -M 1Tli6y-0002Xo-KW
delivering 1Tli6y-0002Xo-KW
Connecting to foobar.TLD [IP.ADDRESS]:25 ... failed: Connection timed out (timeout=5m)
LOG: MAIN
foobar.TLD [IP.ADDRESS] Connection timed out
LOG: MAIN
== info@foobar.TLD R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
```

I have searched on net, and I have found thread on this forum, similar error - http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/t-remote_smtp-defer-53-retry-time-not-reached-any-host-72383.html

and there is proposed solution, but I am not sure should it work in my case. I can not risk loosing emails in queue, my clients would hang me :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see your server is unable to connect remote server to send your mail. Because you are getting "**25 ... failed: Connection timed out**" error in logs. I think your mail server IP is blacklisted in anti-spam databases and maybe due to that you are getting this issues.

Comment: More likely your ISP is filtering port 25 outbound.

Answer (score 0):

run command

```
exim -bt info@foobar.tld
```

Copy ip address and add your CSF white list.

Or turn of Firewall and retest.